# Display fractions in normal fonts with subscripts attached to the terms

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I would be grateful if someone could help me write a fraction in normal text with subscripts attached.

This is the latex code I wrote

```
\begin{equation} 
    v= \frac{ \triangle \text{Z} }{ \text{a\textsubscript{2}-a\textsubscript{1}}}     
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please clarify what `\triangle` is supposed to mean. E.g., are you using the symbol in lieu of `\Delta`? Please also clarify what you mean by "normal text". E.g., are you looking to enter an inline math formula, as opposed to a "displayed" formula that's centered on a line by itself?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `$v = \frac{\Delta Z}{a_2-a_1}$`?

Comment: @mico yes please \triangle for \Delta. I thought maybe \Delta may give the default font for math package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly what you mean by "a fraction in normal text" and "subscripts attached". Anyway, here are two possibilities.

[image]

If the second possibility is what you're looking for, and if you want to typeset all mathematics in upright lettering, I suggest you (a) load the [mathastext](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) package and (b) remove all `\mathrm` wrappers from the formulas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$
\dfrac{\Delta Z}{a_2-a_1}
\qquad
\dfrac{\triangle\mathrm{Z}}{\mathrm{a}_2-\mathrm{a}_1}
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The \mathrm worked. Thank you